# One of my monitors taking 5-7 min to wake up

Tags: display

I have 2 SyncMaster 2043bw Samsung monitors that are connected to my PC.

Last night I turn them off before I went to bed and this morning I tried to turn them on.

One of them turned on after 1 sec and the other just didn't respond (the On/Off light didn't even turn on).

After 2 minutes or so the On/Off light was blinking for another 5-6 min and just after that the monitor turned on.

What is the problem? I tried to disconnect the power cable and then connect it back, also the DVI cable. Nothing worked.

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solve it !***

OK so that's the solution for the problem (in my case).

i opened my screen (with screwdriver) and found on the power board that 2 of the capacitors are blown away. (the top was swollen)

so i just go to electricity store and bought 2 new capacitors.
(the same as the two i solder out !)
I solder them to the board and now it's work like its should be.

I'm not sure that solution will help everyone but its worth a shot !

Comment: It should be noted that you have to buy capacitors that match the ratings on the originals. I had a similar problem and fix on an old HP screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience with my SyncMaster 203B. I guess that it's happening because of its age (quite old) and problems might be in backlight. My screen is OK after 3-4 mins after start.

[This website](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/941094-samsung-syncmaster-932bw-screen-shuts-off-after-2-3-seconds/) offers this solution:

> backlight/backlight inverter is done for.
>   had this problem with dozens of POS-monitors.
>   edit; Try lighting the screen up with a flashlight. If the backlight is broken, you will see the picture on the screen.

My display is really old so I'm not in your position. I'll probably buy a new one ;]

Comment: Hi ! iv'e try to lighting the screen with a flashlight(from my phone) but noting happens its still black.
i have this monitors for 5-6 years